# Re-position footer and force it to drop below blog post excerpts on home page

Tags: footer

Site is under construction using a customized [blank theme](http://www.gracechurchhouston.com)

On my blog page, the footer cuts across the blog posts and it appears my footer is at an absolute position since it is at exactly the same spot on all pages. I need the footer to appear at the end of the final blog post/excerpt on Blog page.

I have tried changing settings for footer in the css and currently have `<footer>` set at `position: absolute` (I'vei tried `relative`, but it lowered the address content on the right side inside the footer) and `#footer-container` set at `position: relative` which works for home page but will not work on the Blog page and probably won't work on the About or Media pages either once I get all the content completed there.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
#page-wrap {
width: 1000px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-bottom: 575px;
}
```

The margin-bottom in that `#page-wrap`is what's causing you the problem.